# function returns address of local variable in c

Tags: c

I make a function to add character to string and I have the next error message function returns address of local variable please help me, my code below.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    char* string;
    string ="hola mundo";
    char c ='x';

    string = cadena_mas_caracter(string,c);
    printf("texto sumado %s",string);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

char *cadena_mas_caracter(char* cadena, char caracter)
{
    int i=0;
    int largo_texto = strlen(cadena)+1;
    char cadena_nueva[largo_texto+1];


    for( i=0; i < largo_texto; i++)
    {
        cadena_nueva[i] = cadena[i];
        if(cadena[i] == '\0')
        {
            cadena_nueva[i]= caracter;
        }
    }

    return cadena_nueva;
}
```

Comment: this will not work, as you're dynamically allocating stack memory in function, and this memory will be freed as soon as you exit from function, you need to allocate heap memory via new/malloc and then free it via delete/free manually

Comment: char cadena_nueva[largo_texto+1]; this is a local variable and scope of local variable within the function. so you can not return address.yes sometimes it may give you correct result if the memory not assigned to other tasks but that does not mean correct.

Comment: yes I understand my local varible is detroy when the method finish and I need put the value out of the stack, but why? I'm trying but I not figured it out, somebody could write code to see the correct form please.

Comment: @Premier: Check my ans, you can make it work if you allocate it on heap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You SHOULD NOT (although yes, sometimes it CAN return the expected result!) return local variable pointer from a function as it is allocated on stack!

Here's an excellent explanation as to why: [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)

To make your code work,replace

```
char cadena_nueva[largo_texto+1];
```

with

```
char* cadena_nueva = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(largo_texto+1));
```

Don't forget to `free()` it when you are done using it

---

It would really help you if you'd read about heap & stack memory storage:

[What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap)
http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html
http://www-ee.eng.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap14/subsection2.1.1.8.html

Comment: should -> must. It's a duplicate, anyway - this is asked every other day.

Comment: Yeah.. I was referring to the same link :)
I said should not becuase it can sometimes return expected answer.

Comment: ok, but as it should be my code.

Comment: Yes, your code exactly does that, ie returning pointer to the local variable. Instead you can allocate memory on the heap ie instead of using `char cadena_nueva[largo_texto+1];`, use `char* cadena_nueva = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(largo_texto+1));`

Comment: ok perfect, now I can try to understand more easily, thanks a lot.

Comment: ok. I will read that information thanks again.